# How to use a definition in Coq?

Tags: coq

Sometimes when I'm proving something, I have a hypothesis `P x y`, and I know that I have a definition like `R x := exists y, P x y`. I would like to add the hypothesis `R x`, but I don't know how to do it. I tried to use `pose proof (R x)`, but I got something of type Prop. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a hypothesis `Hxy: P x y`, you can write
`assert (Rx: R x) by (exists y; assumption).`

On the other direction, if you have a hypothesis `Hx: R x`, the tactic `destruct Hx as [y Pxy]` adds the witness `y`and the corresponding hypothesis to your context.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new argument to your lemma, and inside the proof, you can then extract a witness `y'` for your `y`. In ssreflect, you could write:

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.

Set Implicit Arguments.
Unset Strict Implicit.
Unset Printing Implicit Defensive.

Variable T : Type.

Variable P : T -> T -> Prop.

Definition R x := exists y, P x y.

Lemma foo x y (p : P x y) (r : R x) : false.
Proof.
move: r => [y' pxy'].
```

EDIT: You can also derive a proof of `R x` directly in the proof of `foo`, as follows:

```
Lemma foo x y (p : P x y) : false.
Proof.
have r : R x by exists y.
move: r => [y' pxy'].
```

or, more succinctly:

```
Lemma foo x y (p : P x y) : false.
Proof.
have [y' pxy'] : R x by exists y.
``
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question asked by the OP.

Comment: This is to address the sentence "I would like to add the hypothesis `R x`, but I don't know how to do it." This is done here by adding one additional parameter, `r`, to the whole lemma. Note that `R` is only a definition, not a `Prop`.

Comment: Oh, sorry: I see the point of your question. One can indeed also add explicitly the `R x` property without having to add  an additional parameter via `have r : R x by exists y.` in the proof of `foo`. I got sidetracked by the use of the word "hypothesis" in the original question.